# How to support extra large screens in Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

According to [this doc page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), Android 2.3 supports extra large screen sizes (xlarge), and you can declare that your apps supports this size by adding `android:xlargeScreens="true"` in the `<supports-screens>` tag in the Manifest file.

But, since my app is targeted for a minimum SDK version of Android 2.1, compilation fails complaining about unknown attribute.

I don't want to use the new SDK because I won't get warnings if I accidentally use 2.3 specific features.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to use the 2.3 SDK because that attribute simply is not known in lower SDKs. However, what you can do is set your target SDK to be 2.1.

Comment: So basically, what this means for HRJ: If he does not want to use the 2.3 SDK he can not use these new features. He has to use it as the target SDK, but then he will not get any warnings if he accidently uses higher-level API on a 2.1 or 2.2 device. I think there is only one way out: Testing the app on a 2.1 emulator.

Comment: @mreichelt Don't forget about the Docs! You can filter by API level so you'll know if your 'cool new APi' needs some magic to work on older versions of the platform.

Comment: @smith324 Of course, I forgot to mention that. But it is often complicated to read the documentation every time one is entering a new method or class in Java code. I believe it would be much better to have appropriate warnings as HRJ also wishes to have. That's why I entered a new feature request: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13905 You can vote for it if you like it! :-)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that element is only supported for Android 2.3. As per the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#table2):

> Note: Android 2.3 (API Level 9)
>   introduced a new attribute for the
>    element:
>   xlargeScreens

I believe that means that you can't, in fact, use that attribute unless you're compiling for Android 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like a charm.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"        
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621642/android-app-should-visible-in-playstore-for-normal-screen-devices-as-well-as-tab) for more assistance.