# Why does Android app run in small window on tablet emulator?

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I have an Android App, it works properly on android phones.  I've downloaded Android 3.0 sdk and created a tablet emulator at 1024x600, using Android 3.0.  When I test my app it runs in a small window centered at the top, using about 1/4 of the screen.

What do I have to change in the app, xml files, or manifest to get it to use the whole tablet screen?

As a side note I also have icons for drawable-ldpi, hdpi and mdpi.

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: In order to tell you what to change we should know what you did.

Comment: What part of what I did would you like to know?  Would you like to see the AndroidManifest? or one of my layouts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android smartPhone app support for Android Tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955375/android-smartphone-app-support-for-android-tablet)

Comment: My app starts like this:    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
The main layout does not specify screen size. How does the table decide on size of the app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The earlier sdk's did not have support for the extra large screens, so you need to specify in the manifest a new sdk version. I'll look up the details, but for now a quick fix is to add:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

to your manifest.

Comment: Here's some good discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650889/how-to-support-extra-large-screens-in-android

and here's some developer documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
this link also has great discussion on resizing.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
was all it needed.  I had min version = 3.  The 2 links from Ian were useful.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on the [`<supports-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) Android manifest element. You probably want `android:largeScreens="true"` and `android:xlargeScreens="true"`.

Comment: actually I think that THIS is the correct solution! Without this support-screens tag, an old app will show the same behavior on higher density phones like the HTC Sensation e.g.!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me like a charm.

```
<supports-screens
 android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"        
 android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621642/android-app-should-visible-in-playstore-for-normal-screen-devices-as-well-as-tab) for more assistance.