# Differences between mobile and tablet development?

Tags: android, tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Android app run in small window on tablet emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398363/why-does-android-app-run-in-small-window-on-tablet-emulator)

i developed an android app. Works fine! :)

I tested it on my tablet and saw that only a part of the screen is used (size of my handydisplay).

What i have to do, that the whole tablet screen is filled?

Do you need any code to say what i have to do?

EDIT: my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="[..]"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.6.2">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  

        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        [...many many other activitys...]
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you setting fill_parent on your main layout ? post your xml...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398363/why-does-android-app-run-in-small-window-on-tablet-emulator

Comment: The application should automatically use the whole screen unless in some way you fixed the size

Comment: post the androidmanifest.xml file you used

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) for supporting tablets and handsets. Do follow up with glenviewjeff's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398677/403455) says:

> Read up on the  Android manifest element. You
>   probably want android:largeScreens="true" and
>   android:xlargeScreens="true".

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redesign your app by combining screens for tablet version, You can handle all sized and density devices using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).