# Android App should visible in playstore for normal screen devices as well as tablets and should appear perfect in both (screen resolution)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, google-play, android-screen

I have recently published android app (sdk version 4.2) in playstore. My requirement is that - this app should be visible in  playstore on both - large screen devices (including Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 p3100), as well as normal screen devices.
I also want my app to be displayed in devices (with version 2.2 - 4.2).

This is the code snippet, I was suggested for fulfilment of my requirement.

```
 <supports-screens
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"        
   android:anyDensity="true" 
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    />
```

**There are two cases, depending on the above code.**

1. ***When I include the above code in manifest.xml***

   Including above code in manifest seems to help me in fulfilling my
   requirement of making my app visible in market for both tablet and
   small screen devices. But, in that case, the app screens covers only
   half screen size of tablet, when downloaded from playstore / market
   as well as it is displayed in a similar manner (covering half screen
   part) while debugging in tablet.
2. ***When I don't include the above code in manifest.xml***

   Not including the above code in manifest, seems to work perfect while debugging the app, as the all screens of the app, are displayed perfectly on normal screen devices (phones) as well as on large / x-large screen devices (tablets), but only in case of debugging. The app becomes invisible in playstore for the tablets.

So, both the cases aren't the solution for my requirement.

permissions and features in manifest as below

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

And here is one of my layout (xml), that consumes only half screen-size when debugging on tablet.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true">

      <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

         <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:background="#0074AF">

            <LinearLayout
               android:paddingLeft="5px"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:weightSum="10">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
                  android:layout_weight="8.8"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                  android:textSize="22sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:text="@string/login"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                   <TextView android:id="@+id/version_no"
                     android:layout_weight="1.2"
                     android:textSize="14sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:textColor="#222222"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:text="@string/version"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_borders"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

             <TextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20px"
              android:text="Username*"
              android:id="@+id/user"/>

             <EditText
               android:id="@+id/name"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
               android:paddingBottom="0dp"
               android:paddingTop="0dp"
               android:singleLine="true"
             />

             <TextView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
               android:paddingBottom="0dp"
               android:paddingTop="0dp"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:textSize="20px"
               android:text="Password*"
               android:id="@+id/pswd" />

             <EditText
              android:id="@+id/pass"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:password="true"
             />

             <TextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20px"
              android:text="AccountId*" />

            <EditText
              android:id="@+id/accid"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:inputType="date"
              android:singleLine="true"
             />

             <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/remember_me" />

             <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               >

             <Button
               style="@style/RedButtons"
               android:layout_width="270dip"
               android:layout_height="50dip"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:paddingBottom="3dp"
               android:paddingTop="3dp"
               android:id="@+id/login"
               android:text="@string/login"
               android:textSize="20sp" />

             <Button
               style="@style/RedButtons"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="0dip"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="70px"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:paddingBottom="3dp"
               android:paddingTop="3dp"
               android:id="@+id/exit"
               android:text="@string/exit"
               android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/new_user_txt"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="16sp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

That works fine while debugging in both tablet and phone, the screens also appear fine, when I remove the code snippet of supports-screens and uses-sdk tags from the manifest.xml. But, that's not the actual solution (as the app will be hidden in playstore, in that case), I guess.

Please, let me know, what can be done in order to get rid off this problem.

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
Try taking that out.  Play may be taking you off because the tab may only have wifi.  In fact, I'm not sure I'd put uses-feature in unless you can't work without it.

Comment: Samsung P3100 has both Wifi and 3g. It is Sim enabled.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation issue... The first approach is the correct one and you have to add/implement all necessary tablet friendly layouts. Please, take a time and read the [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Like @shoe rat said it is a layout problem. The <supports-screens/> tag is used to filter your app in play store and cannot affect the layout. I suggest you to post the .xml layout file wich as you said (is covering half screen part)

Comment: If your layout .xml file is in **layout** folder try to copy it in **layout-large** folder also and see what happens.

Comment: And remember to check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zooming behavior is known as "screen compatibility mode".  Google recommends changing your layout not to require this mode.  Then you can keep your `<supports-screens>` element the way you have it.

I haven't tried this, but it seems like the `largestWidthLimitDp` attribute could be used to force the use of screen compatibility mode for larger devices.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"        
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you

```
  <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"        
  />

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

Comment: So, do you mean, on using this, I don't need to make any changes in my layout (xml), and only this change will do everything for me?

Comment: I tried using this, but even this doesn't seem helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me perfiectly

```
<compatible-screens  
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true"
 />
```

and define minsdk version as 1 (ie. for all version of devices)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"/>
```

if your apps doesnot support in android version less than 8 then use this code in your splashscreen activity to prevent from crash the apps

```
if( Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 8){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please upgrade your phone to 2.2+", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
```